# Hibernate + spring error

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to build an app with hibernate + spring + JFS, but I got this errors when I run the app, I've searched about this but I couldn't find anything.

I think this is the maing error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)

```
 SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:736)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 21 more

sep 17, 2015 10:33:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:736)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 21 more
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered similar error. In my case, there was conflict between following depdencies :

1. Hibernate Annotations :

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Hibernate Commons Annotations :

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

I resolved the conflict by removing both the dependencies and using following one :

Hibernate Commons Annotations » 5.0.1.Final

```
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
```

Hope this might help someone.

Comment: This helped me. If you are already including 5.0.1.Final you do not need the other Hibernate imports or .jars

Comment: Surely, by removing artifact *hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar* from the dependency or Build Path will bring you out from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've got incompatible jars on your classpath. If you're not using Maven or another dependency management tool I suggest that you do.

If you are using Maven check for specified dependencies where versions do not match.

Comment: I'm not  using maven, the version of spring  3.2.2 and hibernate 5.0.1 but there is one jar on hibernate that is 3.5.6, hibernate annotations. I quit that jar and i got the same error

Comment: I would strong recommend that you don't mess around trying to guess the correct combinations of jars. Let Maven pull them in transitively.