# Hibernate Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jersey, web.xml, persistence.xml

I'm using Jersey as Rest web service and Hibernate entity manager to persist JPA models. and I'm using Tomcat 8 as container.

Here is the content of the persistence.xml file :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">

        <properties>

            <!--PostgreSQL-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation" value="disabled"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my Rest call is as simple as this :

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public Response test() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

and here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>ca.products.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>

      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But it gives me this error :

```
type Rapport d''exception

message java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:736)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:709)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:185)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    ca.products.services.RestServices.test(RestServices.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I was not be able to figure out where is the problem !! any help ?

as suggested, here is the mvn dependency:tree log :

```
[INFO] ca.products.jpa_module:jpa_module:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:5.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:jar:5.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-persist:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

Comment: Are you using any build tool such as `Maven` or `Gradle`? Usually, this sort of error is due to library mismatch. Please look at the jar file dependency tree. Both these tools are able to provide the dependency tree for the list of jars called.

Comment: I'm using Maven , and I've run mvn dependency:tree and nothing I can see as not correct !! I'll paste the mvn tree in the post thanks!

Comment: You have right @RavindranKanniah :) there is issue with the dependencies : to correct the things I've used only   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> instead of   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> and <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>

Comment: This sort of issue is real pain but requires patience because it is time consuming to debug. I suggest look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635649/hibernate-spring-error which is similar to yours in terms of error. Anyway try to down grade some `Hibernate` jars to see whether the error is still there.

Comment: Yes :) thanks @RavindranKanniah

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the comment of @Ravindran Kanniah here is the answer :

There is dependencies' conflict between   hibernate-core  and 
hibernate-annotations

So I've corrected my maven pom.xml by commenting the artifact giving the conflict :

```
<!--Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
```

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party... but this is not the solution.? What if we need both `hibernate-annotations` and `hibernate-core`?