# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addAttributeConverter(new BirthdayConverter());

```
    **configuration.registerTypeOverride(new JsonBinaryType());
```

** // It doesnt work

```
    configuration.configure();

    try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = User.builder()
                .username("john@gmail.com")
                .firstname("John")
                .lastname("Jones")
                .info("""
                        {
                        "name": "John",  
                        "id": 25   
                        }
                        """)
                .birthdate(new Birthday(LocalDate.of(1998, 6, 21)))
                .role(Role.ADMIN)
                .build();
        session.persist(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

entity/User.class

```
//@Type(type = "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType")
@Convert(converter = JsonBinaryType.class) 
private String info;
```

}

Always getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer

Changed @Type(type = "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType") to @Convert(converter = JsonBinaryType.class)

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.3.1.Final'
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6'

    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-parent:2.10.3'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.21.1'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7'

   }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Please try adding `implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'` to your gradle file. or in your syntax `implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.1"`

Comment: Added. Now getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.<init>(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptor, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptor)'
 at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.AbstractHibernateType.<init>(AbstractHibernateType.java:27)
 at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.<init>(JsonBinaryType.java:36)
 at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.<clinit>(JsonBinaryType.java:33)

Comment: try reading up here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407235/hibernate-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror