# How to fix my first Hibernate JAVA program

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I created a new Maven project , I installed JBoss tools in Eclipse Kepler (including Hibernate) and I wanted to test a Hibernate program so I did this program below, but when I run as Java program I get errors / exceptions.

Here are my files :

[image: Structure]

File SaveStudent.java :

```
package com.hibernate.demo;

import com.hibernate.entity.student;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class SaveStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory f = new Configuration()
                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                        .addAnnotatedClass(student.class)
                        .buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = f.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            System.out.println("Creating student...");
            student st = new student("X","X","xx@xx.xx");

            session.getTransaction();

            System.out.println("Saving ...");
            session.save(st);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!!!");

        } finally {
            session.close();
            f.close();
        }

    }

}
```

File student.java :

```
package com.hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="hbstudent")
public class student {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="last")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

public student (){
}

public student(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "student [id=" + id + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname="
            + lastname + ", email=" + email + "]";
}



}
```

Here is my POM.XML :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>hibernate-tuto</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-tuto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
                 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Beta2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>

            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Beta2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hibernate Configuration file :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

The error I get :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.hibernate.demo.SaveStudent.main(SaveStudent.java:16)
```

Comment: Look into making a Log4j.properties file that you will add to your classpath.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685510/log4j-warning-while-initializing you can just add the line BasicConfigurator.configure(); to get around the issues your having

Comment: It's because there's conflict between your hibernate dependencies. Why have you added so many same dependencies of different versions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

It is getting clash with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[click here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635649/hibernate-spring-error)