# getting error in my spring programme

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
```

> while connection to hibernate connection I am getting such type of
>   error.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635649/hibernate-spring-error/35015624#35015624). In my case, there was conflict between following depdencies :

1. Hibernate Annotations :

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Hibernate Commons Annotations :

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

I resolved the conflict by removing both the dependencies and using following one :

Hibernate Commons Annotations » 5.0.1.Final

```
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
```

Hope this might help someone.